# Append the total count of same values in array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a column of text values. A value may occur more than once. I want to change the values such that occurrences of the same value are (legibly) numbered. I have added input and desired output to clarify this.

Can't figure out how to append the sum to each similar values in the array, i can actually count similar values to get the sum since i am comparing the array values but how do you go back to the values and append the sum as shown in desired output

To be more clear also it should only count successive similar values, if a similar values appear later in the list it should just have its own count at sum appended

This is my **input**

[image]

This is my **desired output**

[image]

This is my code:

```vb
    Sub groupindexcells()
        Dim arr As Variant
        Dim rlast As Long, i As Long, rsum As Long
        Dim comparevalue
    
        rlast = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        arr = Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & rlast).Value
        rsum = 1
        
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr) - 1
            If comparevalue = "" Then
                If arr(i, 1) = arr(i + 1, 1) Then
                    arr(i, 1) = arr(i, 1) & "-" & rsum
                    rsum = rsum + 1
                Else
                    arr(i, 1) = arr(i, 1) & "-" & rsum
                    comparevalue = arr(i + 1, 1)
                    rsum = 1
                End If
            Else
                If arr(i, 1) = comparevalue Then
                    If arr(i, 1) = arr(i + 1, 1) Then
                        arr(i, 1) = arr(i, 1) & "-" & rsum
                        rsum = rsum + 1
                    Else
                        comparevalue = arr(i + 1, 1)
                        arr(i, 1) = arr(i, 1) & "-" & rsum
                        rsum = 1
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        
        'append the index for the last row
        If arr(UBound(arr), 1) = comparevalue Then
            arr(UBound(arr), 1) = arr(UBound(arr), 1) & "-" & rsum
        Else
            arr(UBound(arr), 1) = arr(UBound(arr), 1) & "-" & 1
        End If
    
        Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & rlast).Value = arr
    End Sub
```

And this is the **current output**

[image]

Comment: I do not see any question in the post. So, what is the question? Or would you like us to change the code completely for you in such away that you get the desired output?

Comment: @Storax yes to modify the code to append the total count of same values as shown in desired ouput

Comment: What specific problem did you run into with your attempt?

Comment: @braX i can actually get the sum count of the similar values since i am comparing the array values but how to go back to each the array value and append the sum ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated to only count consecutive similar values.

I have added variables `NewValue` and `EachTotal`.

```
Sub groupindexcells()
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim rlast As Long, i As Long, rsum As Long
    Dim comparevalue
    Dim NewValue As Boolean
    Dim EachTotal As Long

    rlast = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    arr = Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & rlast).Value
    rsum = 1
    
    NewValue = True
    EachTotal = 0
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr) - 1
        If comparevalue = "" Then
            
            If NewValue = True Then
                j = i
                Do While arr(i, 1) = arr(j, 1)
                    EachTotal = EachTotal + 1
                    j = j + 1
                    If j > UBound(arr) Then Exit Do
                Loop
            End If
        
            If arr(i, 1) = arr(i + 1, 1) Then
                NewValue = False
                arr(i, 1) = arr(i, 1) & "-" & rsum & " of " & EachTotal
                rsum = rsum + 1
            Else
                arr(i, 1) = arr(i, 1) & "-" & rsum & " of " & EachTotal
                comparevalue = arr(i + 1, 1)
                rsum = 1
                NewValue = True
                EachTotal = 0
            End If
        Else
            
            If NewValue = True Then
                'new
                j = i
                Do While arr(i, 1) = arr(j, 1)
                    EachTotal = EachTotal + 1
                    j = j + 1
                    If j > UBound(arr) Then Exit Do
                Loop
            End If
        
            If arr(i, 1) = comparevalue Then
                If arr(i, 1) = arr(i + 1, 1) Then
                    NewValue = False
                    arr(i, 1) = arr(i, 1) & "-" & rsum & " of " & EachTotal
                    rsum = rsum + 1
                Else
                    comparevalue = arr(i + 1, 1)
                    arr(i, 1) = arr(i, 1) & "-" & rsum & " of " & EachTotal
                    rsum = 1
                    NewValue = True
                    EachTotal = 0
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
    'append the index for the last row
    If arr(UBound(arr), 1) = comparevalue Then
        arr(UBound(arr), 1) = arr(UBound(arr), 1) & "-" & rsum & " of " & EachTotal
    Else
        arr(UBound(arr), 1) = arr(UBound(arr), 1) & "-" & 1
    End If

    Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & rlast).Value = arr
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the code,my bad i was not clear,but it should only count successive similar values, if the same values appear later on in the list it should have a different count and sum